# Motivation for Proposition 3.14 from Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-space-isomorphism, tangent-spaces

In Lee's book Smooth manifolds he introduces the following proposition

> **Proposition 3.14** (The Tangent Space to a Product Manifold). Let $M_1,\dots, M_k$ be smooth manifolds, and for each $j$, let $\pi_j : M_1 \times \dots \times M_k \to 
> M_j$ be the projection onto the $M_j$ factor. For any point $p = (p_1, \dots, p_k) \in M_1 \times \dots \times M_k$ the map $$\alpha : T_p(M_1 \times \dots \times M_k) \to T_{p_1}M_1 \oplus \dots \oplus T_{p_k}M_k$$ defined by $$\alpha(v)=(d(\pi_1)_p(v), \dots,d(\pi_k)_p(v))$$ is an isomorphism.

He leaves the proof as an exercise which I couldn't do, but found the solution to. On the next page he states that

> Once again, because the isomorphism  is canonically defined, independently
> of any choice of coordinates, we can consider it as a canonical identification, and we
> will always do so. Thus, for example, we identify $T_{(p,q)}(M \times N)$ with $T_pM\oplus T_qN$ and treat $T_pM$ and $T_qN$ as subspaces of $T_{(p,q)}(M \times N)$.

This is where I'm getting confused. I don't understand what is he trying to communicate here?

In the solution for the problem for the case where we only have two manifolds $M$ and $N$ it's first shown that $\alpha$ is linear and then that it has an inverse $\beta$ as $$\beta : T_p M \oplus T_q N \to T_{(p,q)} (M \times N)$$ defined by $$\beta(u,w)=d(\iota_M)_p(v) +d(\iota_N)_q(w)$$ where the inclusions are as $\iota_M : M \to M\times N$ and map $M$ to $M \times \{q\}$ and likewise for $\iota_N$.

Now I think there is a connection here the way that the inclusions are defined and what Lee stated about the canonical isomorphism, but I don't see how? I've tried to find some simpler examples of this online, but there isn't any.

If anyone could explain the motivation for defining the inverse $\beta$ with the inclusions as it is that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why the downvote? I think my question is quite clear.

Comment: I agree with OP that their question is well stated

Comment: Is your question what precisely the idea of a "canonical identification" is, or is your question about the inverse $\beta$? Because I think those are two fairly separate concerns.

Comment: They are indeed. My question is about the "idea" for the inverse $\beta$. I don't see where the motivation comes to consider the differentials of the inclusions $\iota_M$ and $\iota_N$. @Thorgott

Comment: An abelian group $M$ is the product of two abelian groups $A$ and $B$ if you can find maps $i_A\colon A\rightarrow M$, $i_B\colon B\rightarrow M$, $p_A\colon M\rightarrow A$ and $p_B\colon M\rightarrow B$, such that $p_Ai_A=id_A$, $p_Bi_B=id_B$, $p_Ai_B=0$, $p_Bi_A=0$ and $i_Ap_A+i_Bp_B=id_M$. These maps take the role of the canonical inclusions/projections. Since we're in a scenario were we do something functorial (take tangent spaces) and hope it preserves products, taking these maps to be the differentials of the inclusions/projections in the geometric sense isn't far-fetched.